# How to use GD library with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, gd

I wanted to use the GD library with cake php but I'm having some problems.
Here is my view.ctp:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$img = @ImageCreate(200, 100);
$color = ImageColorAllocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
ImagePng($img);
?>
```

But when I try to see my page, here is what I get:

```
�PNG IHDR�d�H�HPLTE��   7IDATH����à�S�U�(~;IEND�B`�
```

My GD Library is well install on my server (It appear in phpinfo())

Any idea why ?

Comment: Your `Content-type` isn't being set correctly here.  I've never used CakePHP, but you may need to use *their* functions to change the header, not the `header` function.

Comment: This is not a GD library problem. Its a problem with the headers being sent at the right time so your browser understands the content as a png image.

Comment: check your error logs for the usual "headers already sent" warnings. your header() call is most likely **NOT** succeeding because of prior output.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new **[view layout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts)** for rendering images like these.

For e.g. create a new layout as 'app/View/Layouts/image.ctp' with the following content

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $this->fetch('content'); 
die();
```

Then in your controller's view action add

```
$this->layout = 'image';
```

This should now set the correct headers for the image.

Comment: Hello, I just tried to implement what you say, but there is some problems, the first one is that I want to keep the template of my 'view.ctp', if I "load" the image.ctp layout, it totally replace my view layout. And the second problem is that is not working, I just get the "thumbnail" of the png missing. Any idea why ?

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to achieve here. If you want to render a image using GD library then that should be a separate view and I cannot think how you can expect to see other data in the image. In other words an image is different from a standard HTML page. If you want to generate an image use the separate layout approach that I suggested. If you want to embed the generated image into your standard layout, then you can embed that in the same way that you'll embed images.

Comment: Ok, I will try to be more precise about what I want to do. Actually, I want to display an image that will be generate from data that I selected from my Database, a kind of bar graph, but I want to use GD. So It will have my view template, and somewhere in the page, the image that I had generate previously with the data. Is that more clear or not ? :/

Comment: I think you will need two views/actions here. (i) /view/id to create the actual page & (ii) /createimage/id to create the image. The first view (page) will include the second view (the image).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `header()` function from within your `view.ctp` file.
The view is rendered after all headers have been sent to the browser.

The best (and actually the only) way to do this is by setting all the header parameters
from your controller.
Check [Setting headers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-headers) and also the [CakeResponse](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse) on how to set different headers.